# How do I use the CD4051 multiplexer with an ESP32?

Tags: multiplexer, esp32

I want to use the CD4051 multiplexer to control 20V signals. The ESP32 is only used to digital write to the multiplexer selector. I am not sure how to wire and power the multiplexer correctly. For some reason, the selector goes to 7 when the VCC isn't connected (5V is connected to channel 7 of the MUX) but selects 0 when the VCC is 20 volts.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use the CD4051 multiplexer to control 20V signals.

20 V is an **absolute maximum** rating, you should not plan to run a device at or near to absolute max.

> The esp32 is only used to digital write to the multiplexer selector. I'm not sure how to wire and power the multiplexer correctly.

- VDD is the positive supply to both logic and switching sections
- VSS is the lower supply for the logic
- VEE is the lower supply for the switch

This is intended to be used with VSS to GND, VDD to 5 V or so, and VEE to -5 V, so that your switched signals can swing above and below GND

If you don't need to switch signals below ground, then ground both VEE and VSS. Your signals **and logic inputs** will need to be between GND and VDD.

> For some reason, the selector goes to 7 when the VCC isn't connected (5V is connected to channel 7 of the MUX)

Without a VCC, 5 V on a channel input will conduct through a protection diode and power the chip. You don't say what the logic outputs of your ESP32 are at this point. However, a conducting protection diode, while it protects the chip, may cause it to malfunction temporarily, as your inputs are outside the permitted range.

> ... but selects 0 when the VCC is 20 Volts.

Taking the VCC to 20 V means that whatever the ESP32 is outputting, whether 0 or 3.3 V, will be taken as a logic 0 by the IC, as it's below 30% of VDD. You need to exceed 70% of VDD to guarantee that the input is seen as a logic 1.

You could use some NPN transistors, or indeed an LM324 (pro tip, they're readily available, dirt cheap, and make very flexible (if slow) FET and high voltage drivers) or LM339 to shift the 3 V logic outputs of your ESP32 up to the rail to rail swing needed to control the 4051, though you're still left with the problem of running it at absolute maximum voltage.

There are other devices available that are more suited to your application. Take a look at the ADG5409 for instance. It's specified to +36 V operation, with 3.3 V logic level inputs. Have a look at similar parts from Analog, Maxim and TI, they may be better suited to your switching configuration and budget, ADG5409 was just the first one I spotted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I think I understand now. I'll try to find some other parts that are available in my area. Thanks again.